# New Win10 and Old YubiKey4; trying to configure GPG Sign for existing key

Tags: digital-signature, windows-10, yubikey, git

I have been using a YubiKey 4 to sign git commits for a few years on Ubuntu.

I am setting up a new Windows10 machine and want to use the same signing key from Windows; however I cannot seem to point gpg at the YubiKey private signing key.

`gpg --card-status` shows me the keys exist on the card (albeit with an unexpected `General key info..: [none]` at the end; I'm not sure if that is important)

`gpg -k` shows me that I have successfully imported the public keys from the card

`gpg -K` shows me a blank space where I was hoping to see a few entries like `ssb> rsa/4096 ...`

I think there must be a distinct step that create the reference; but I've no idea what it is

Is this sounding familiar? Any suggestions how to proceed

I installed gpg4win, version looks like

```
C:\Users\ben>where gpg
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe

C:\Users\ben>gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.23
libgcrypt 1.8.6
```

I am running Windows 10 Version 2004 Build 19041.572